# Evaluation of multiple models using GridSearchCV and f2 score

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to classify some machine learning models in a binary classification using GridSearchCV. I want to classify the models with respect of score, best parameters and f2 score.

For the score and best parameters I used the code

```
scores = []

for model_name, mp in model_params.items():
    clf =  GridSearchCV(mp['model'], mp['params'], cv=5, return_train_score=False)
    clf.fit(X_test, y_test)
    scores.append({
        'model': model_name,
        'best_score': clf.best_score_,
        'best_params': clf.best_params_
    })
    
df = pd.DataFrame(scores,columns=['model','best_score','best_params'])
```

Which gives the `best_score` and `best_params` for all the models, but I am not able to do it find the f2 score of all the models. What should be the code?

Answer (score 1):

```
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer,fbeta_score
def f2_func(y_true, y_pred):
    f2_score = fbeta_score(y_true, y_pred, beta=2)
    return f2_score

def my_f2_scorer():
    return make_scorer(f2_func)

clf = GridSearchCV(svm.SVC(), parameters, cv=10, scoring=my_f2_scorer())
```

Comment: Please add a detailed explanation to your answer to further clarify how your code solves the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at `clf.cv_results_` which holds the scores and other benchmark informations for all models searched (see also [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html))

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to make it shorter:

```
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, fbeta_score
f2_scorer = make_scorer(fbeta_score, beta=2)
```

And use it in this way in the GridSearch:

```
clf =  GridSearchCV(mp['model'], mp['params'], cv=5, scoring=f2_scorer)
```

We have created a custom scorer with fbeta_score, that is the implementation of F2 in scikit-learn. Then you only have to use this custom scorer in the GridSearch. More information about [fbeta_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.fbeta_score.html).